# Difference between graphical layout and emulator

Tags: android

My graphical layout view and the running emulator view is different. I made a landscape layout which shows different in running emulator than the graphical layout's view.What can I do to match them (at least 95%). I wonder if it shows different again in real device..

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the graphical layout view and emulator view will be different. You can view the layout in  Graphical layout same as emulator by changing the views(either landscape or portrait) and device type as shown in below images:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanx a lot, did as u said but yet its showing different from emulator in landscape mode. BTW, how did u get the screen shot of that portion? I'll post mine. But I find 1 difference my emulator skin is set to HVGA whereas in graphical layout its set to 2.7in QVGA

Comment: press Print Screen button on ur keyboard and paste the same in PhotoEditing tool like MSPaint.

Comment: But I find 1 difference my emulator skin is set to HVGA whereas in graphical layout its set to 2.7in QVGA ( as in ur 2nd image)

Comment: change that to 3.2in HVGA slider(ADP1). The default view of emulator is this 1 only

Comment: Could u explain  bit about 3.2in HVGA slider(ADP1). HVGA slider and ADP1 ?

Comment: yeah please find this link:http://developer.android.com/intl/ja/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: Please ACCEPT and UPVOTE the answer if u found the solution